# Pascal to Assembly compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I'm working on a compiler project, I've written my lexer.l and parser.y and it 
work correctly on my friends computers, but I get the following error:

---

pascal.tab.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

---

this is my Makefile:

```
FLEX = /usr/bin/flex
CFLAGS = -g
LDLIBS = -lfl
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
BISON = /usr/bin/bison

pascal: pascal.tab.o pascal.lex.o
        $(CC) -o pascal pascal.tab.o pascal.lex.o $(LDLIBS)
pascal.lex.o:   pascal.lex.c pascal.tab.h
        $(CC) -c pascal.lex.c 
pascal.tab.o:   pascal.tab.c pascal.tab.h
        $(CC) -c pascal.tab.c 
pascal.tab.c:   pascal.y
        $(BISON) -d pascal.y
pascal.lex.c:   pascal.l
        $(FLEX) pascal.l
        mv  lex.yy.c pascal.lex.c

clean:
        rm  pascal.tab.o pascal.lex.o pascal.tab.c pascal.lex.c \
           pascal.tab.h pascal
```

---

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you by any chance copy the entire source tree from your friend's computer? Does your friend by any chance use a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You have not said what kinds of computer you and your friend have. In this case it might be important information as it seems to work on one and not the other. You also did not say what command you had typed when getting the error. That might have been critical on getting some help also!

However, the `pascal.tab.o` file will have been made by a compiler, probably gcc. It is quite normal that binary files are not portable between different computers. Sometimes, even when you have linked the `*.o` files to make an executable file that executable will not work on another computer because it is incompatible with the software being used. The program `ld` that generated this error is the linker which combines these binary files.

We cannot expect a binary file built on a PC running Windows to be usable on a Mac or an iPhone. We cannot expect a linux compiler to build a binary  that will run on a Mac either. However binaries built on different versions of windows are not interchangeable and similarly binaries from different kinds of linux are equally not interchangeable. You would not expect an iPhone app executable to work on Android would you?

You should still be able to transfer the file `lexer.l` and `parser.y` and run them through the flex/bison tools and gcc to get a working program again.

(Update)

Now I see your makefile, I guess you copied all your  files from your friends computer, including the `makefile`. The solution is easy for you:

```
make clean
make
```

These two commands should remove the incompatible binaries and create new ones on your computer, and you should be good to go.

Comment: ... or even the C files generated by flex and bison on the other machine, in case flex and bison are not installed on this machine. (Although they're probably easy enough to install.)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, this is my Makefile with all the commands : FLEX = /usr/bin/flex
CFLAGS = -g
LDLIBS = -lfl
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
BISON = /usr/bin/bison

pascal: pascal.tab.o pascal.lex.o
 $(CC) -o pascal pascal.tab.o pascal.lex.o $(LDLIBS)
pascal.lex.o: pascal.lex.c pascal.tab.h
 $(CC) -c pascal.lex.c 
pascal.tab.o: pascal.tab.c pascal.tab.h
 $(CC) -c pascal.tab.c 
pascal.tab.c: pascal.y
 $(BISON) -d pascal.y
pascal.lex.c: pascal.l
 $(FLEX) pascal.l
 mv  lex.yy.c pascal.lex.c

clean:
 rm  pascal.tab.o pascal.lex.o pascal.tab.c pascal.lex.c \
            pascal.tab.h pascal